# How to make sure JWT authenticated users will only have access to their own resources

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, jwt, bearer-token, asp.net-core-identity

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core WebAPI using the JWT Bearer Authentication middleware and ASP.NET Core Identity.

**Startup.cs :**

```
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
               ...
            }
        });
```

**AuthController.cs**

```
    [ValidateModel]
    [HttpPost("api/auth/token")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Token([FromBody] Credential model)
    {
        try
        {
            var applicationUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (applicationUser != null)
            {
                if (_hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(applicationUser, applicationUser.PasswordHash, model.Password) == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
                {
                    var token = await CreateTokenAsync(applicationUser);

                    return Ok(new
                    {
                        token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                        expiration = token.ValidTo
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Exception thrown while creating JWT: {ex}");
        }

        return BadRequest("Failed to generate token");
    }
```

Everything works just fine. When I try to access a controller with the [Authorize] attribute on top, I get a 401 if the bearer header is missing, otherwise a 200.

I want to go further and ensure a user can only be able to retrieve his own data.

The generated token payload contains these informations :

```
{
  "sub": "mail@test.com",
  "jti": "user Guid in database",
  "exp": someexpirationdate,
  "iss": "http://someurl",
  "aud": "http://someurl"
}
```

How can I access the jti value in my controllers' methods to ensure the users are actually asking for a resource that belongs to them?

**EDIT**

Does that seem ok?

```
var test = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

if(test != id.ToString())
{
    return BadRequest("Failed to get user");
}
```

Where "id" is a Guid parameter of my action

Thanks

Comment: Have you try to get the associate claim from your token ?

Comment: As I understand, using claims will allow me to policy-based authorize my users to access resources, not to ensure users only access resources that belong to them

Comment: Have a look on this post to better understand the concept of claims https://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-authorisation-in-asp-net-core/